# who's printing the "</form" tag

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to debug a web form that's missing some fields.  This is what the rendered HTML looks like: 
(notice where the form is located)

```
     <tr>
        <td>
            <a tabindex="1" href="index.php?module=redirect&amp;page=rackspace&amp;tab=editrows&amp;op=deleteRow&amp;row_id=18" title="Delete row" class="input">
                <img src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-user-trash-16x16.png" title="Delete row" height="16" width="16" border="0">
            </a>
            <form method="post" id="updateRow" name="updateRow" action="?module=redirect&amp;page=rackspace&amp;tab=editrows&amp;op=updateRow">
                <input tabindex="1" name="row_id" value="18" type="hidden">
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="location_name">usa</div></td><td><div id="name" name="name" value="usa-room1">usa-room1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input tabindex="1" name="edit" class="edit" src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/pencil-icon.png" id="16" title="Edit row" type="image" border="0">&nbsp;
            <input tabindex="1" style="display: none;" name="submit" class="icon" src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-document-save-16x16.png" title="Save changes" type="image" border="0">
        </td>
        <td><a href="index.php?page=row&amp;row_id=18">Row usa-room1</a></td>
    </tr>
```

I would like to change this code so the form wraps the entire . 
I've been reviewing the PHP code that generates this code and I can't see why / what is creating the  tag.

Here's the code that calls a function that auto generates the  tag with the correct parameters:

```
    foreach (listCells ('row') as $row_id => $rowInfo)
    {
            echo '<tr><td>';
            if ($rc = $rowInfo['rackc'])
                    printImageHREF ('nodestroy', "${rc} rack(s) here");
            else
                    echo getOpLink (array('op'=>'deleteRow', 'row_id'=>$row_id), '', 'destroy', 'Delete row');
            printOpFormIntro ('updateRow', array ('row_id' => $row_id));
    exit;           
    echo "this is after ok??!?!?";
```

The exit statement and the echo after it is me trying to prove the code doesn't get any further than that.

"printOpFormInfo" is the function that prints the form tag.  Here's what it looks like:

```
function printOpFormIntro($opname, $extra = array(), $upload = FALSE)
{
        global $pageno, $tabno, $page;

        echo "<form method=post id=${opname} name=${opname} action='?module=redirect&page=${pageno}&tab=${tabno}&op=${opname}'";
        if ($upload)
                echo " enctype='multipart/form-data'";
        echo ">";
exit;
echo "<font color=red>YOU SHOULD NOT GET HERE</font>";
        fillBypassValues ($pageno, $extra);
        foreach ($extra as $inputname => $inputvalue)
                printf ('<input type=hidden name="%s" value="%s">', htmlspecialchars ($inputname, ENT_QUOTES), htmlspecialchars ($inputvalue, ENT_QUOTES));
}
```

Once again, I've included an "exit" statement to track line by line the code.

Running the code as is, I get the following HTML printed:

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="index.php?module=redirect&amp;page=rackspace&amp;tab=editrows&amp;op=deleteRow&amp;row_id=17" title="Delete row" class="input">
       <img src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-user-trash-16x16.png" title="Delete row" height="16" width="16" border="0"></a>
       <form method="post" id="updateRow" name="updateRow" action="?module=redirect&amp;page=rackspace&amp;tab=editrows&amp;op=updateRow"></form>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Notice the **closing** form tag.  I can't seeem to find where / what is creating it. 
I think I've been looking at this code too long.  A fresh pair of eyes would be appreciated.

Comment: what IDE are you using ?

Comment: Are you checking this with a View Source in a browser or are you using the Browser's development tools?  I ask because Browser Development tools show you the rendered DOM including any HTML elements that were inserted because they didn't exist (such as a missing form close tag).

Comment: @Powerlord I was using the f12 tools in firefox.  So it's probably adding in the html for me.  So to see what's rendered via code should I just do a view source?.

Comment: @dot Yes, you should.

Comment: @Powerlord, ok I think that's whats going on.  thanks.  +1 for that